# Heat and the evolution of certain thermodynamics systems

Tags: thermodynamics, water, equilibrium

I would like to understand,from a macroscopic approach, the evolution of thermodynamical properties whithin certain systems :

1) There is water inside an isulated vessel at 100°C, 1 Atm. I can´t assure whether it is steam, liquid, or a mixture of both (but ratio unknown). Since it is in Vapor- Liquid equilibrium, either phases are stable in that thermodynamic state. Am I right?

2) Boiling water in an open pot, since the vapor pressure definition applies to closed systems would it mean that as the vapor over the boiling water blows away new vapor is form at a rate that sustain 1 atm of vapor pressure?

3) Inside an insulated vessel at 1atm the is water at 100°C and a metal rod at 100°C, since there is no temperature gradient there is no net heat transfer and water still liquid. In other words, in order to transmit latent heat, there must be a temperature difference.

4) A source heats water inside a vessel (V=constant). As soon as boiling begins, pressure raise up. How will the system evolve? Depends on the heat? 
How would be the relationship between the temperature (Cv) and pressure increasement as the steam (under Tc) is being heated? May condensation occur?

5) How come water inside a vacuum chamber decreases its temperature while boiling? It comes to my mind that the energy spent changing phase results in a temperature drop.
Pump keeps sucking through the whole process so it's considered an open system. When the pressure reaches the boiling point at room temperature, should the pressure maintain constant till water transform entirely into steam?

I wrote water as the substance to be examined, but the concepts may apply to several fluids.
I hope I have made this sufficiently clear. English is not my native language.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Under item (2), the water vapor forms primarily below the surface of the water in the pot, where there is no air present.  So the bubbles are pure water vapor, and they are released into the air after they have risen to the surface.  The partial pressure of the water vapor within the room air is much much lower than 1 atm.  The circulation of the room air carries the water vapor released from the bubble away from the surface where it mixes with the room air.